# CAML Filtering on the Server Side

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

I have a filter coming from some location (let's say, query string):

```
<ParameterBinding Name="param" Location="QueryString(param)"/>
```

I know how to pass that parameter to a CAML query, which would be something like:

```
<Where>
  <Eq>
    <FieldRef Name='SomeField'/>
    <Value Type='Text'>{param}</Value>
  </Eq>
</Where>
```

However, if the parameter is not supplied, I will get nothing (SomeField = '').

I was wondering: is it possible to have parameters as field values in CAML? For example, I know this doesn't work, but you get the idea:

```
<Where>
  <Or>
    <Eq>
      <FieldRef Name='SomeField'/>
      <Value Type='Text'>{param}</Value>
    </Eq>
    <Eq>
      <FieldRef Formula='{param}'/>
      <Value Type='Text'></Value>
    </Eq>
  </Or>
</Where>
```

I know that according to the CAML schema, it doesn't seem possible. This way, I could have truly server-side filtering. The alternative with XSL is client-side, which means, more records will be retrieved that are necessary.

Yes, I know I could do this programmatically, but that is not my intent. I wish to use the XsltListViewWebPart.

Any thoughts? Any alternatives?

Comment: Unless you want to (as suggested by yourself) do some coding these situations are solved by using calculated fields, http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/3b5f966d-77e3-4470-b0df-7a28914287cc/caml-query-using-conditions-on-parameters?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy

Comment: These situations cannot be solved properly by using calculated field, because I would have to create one empty calculated field for every list, which makes it a non-generic solution. I know about the link you sent, that's exactly the kind of problem I'm facing. And using XSLT filtering only happens on the "client-side", which is not good for performance.

Comment: Well what webpart are you using? If you use CQWP you can add RenderOnServer=true to your querystring or implement AlwaysRenderOnServer (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.search.webcontrols.contentbysearchwebpart.alwaysrenderonserver.aspx?ocid=aff-n-we-loc--ITPRO40936&WT.mc_id=aff-n-we-loc--ITPRO40936)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I fail to understand your point... I am using XsltListViewWebPart, but that really doesn't matter: XSLT filtering is applied "client-side", that is, after records are retrieved from SharePoint and sent to the XSLT engine. I can very easily retrieve all records from SharePoint and then filter on the XSLT, but this is terrible from a performance point of view. I am already rendering on the server.

Comment: Well that webpart implements both ServerRender and ClientRender properties, have you configured it using them?

Comment: You are totally missing the point, thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Got it:

```
<Where>
    <Or>
        <Geq>
            <FieldRef Name='SomeField'/>
            <Value Type='Number'>{param}</Value>
        </Geq>
        <Contains>
            <FieldRef Name='Author'/>
            <Value Type='Text'><![CDATA[{param}]]></Value>
        </Contains>
    </Or>
</Where>
```

The trick is to have in the second condition something that will be true. In this case, if {param} is not supplied, it will be '', and thus it will be contained by the Author (Created By) field, which is always not empty. The problem was that I had to surround {param} with , otherwise, it won't work.